# Can I focus a dynamically loaded AJAX element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My scenario is that I have a form on my page. My client would like to be able to fill out the form completely without ever touching the mouse. The problem is that I have a sort of "auto-complete" function that searches our DB (via AJAX) for similar entries, and dynamically loads them into a select element. Then you are able to click the entry that you'd like to have "auto-complete" the form.

To please my client, I am trying to find a way to have that dynamic select element acquire focus once it is loaded, so that the user can press the arrow keys and enter to select what they want, without using the mouse.

After googling for solutions, I have tried adding

```
    document.getElementById('ajaxbox').focus();
```

into the function called when onreadystatechange is triggered. I have also tried adding that line as a script, and write the script in when the select box is written to the page. Neither of these have worked (either for reasons I can't determine or because I get the error that ajaxbox is null, telling me that it's trying to call the focus() before the box is loaded on the page).

Any ideas? I can provide further information, but not a functioning sample page. Javascript or JQuery solutions are preferred.

EDIT:
Added some code. The URL referenced in the first function is to a java servlet that writes the dynamic html onto the page (via a print writer). I can't really change that currently (due to time constraints). This is all inherited code, so please let me know if there are things that could/should change. I won't be offended.

Here is a portion of the javascript where I was trying to set the focus.

```
    function xmlreqGET(url) {
//alert('ajax');
    var xmlhttp=false;
    var xmlreq;
    try {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, etc.
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlreq = new CXMLReq('', xmlhttp);
            xmlreqs.push(xmlreq);
            urlAr.push(url);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = xmlhttpChange;
            //alert(url);
            xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
} else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    if (xmlhttp) {
                    xmlreq = new CXMLReq('', xmlhttp);
                    xmlreqs.push(xmlreq);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = xmlhttpChange;
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
        }
    } catch (e) { }
  }


function xmlhttpChange() {
if (typeof(window['xmlreqs']) == "undefined") {
        return;
    }
    try {

    if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
        for (var i=0; i < xmlreqs.length; i++) {

                if (xmlreqs[i].xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                        if (xmlreqs[i].xmlhttp.status == 200 || xmlreqs[i].xmlhttp.status == 304) {
                                // 200 OK
                                // get response info here before splicing - see below on creating an xml object
                                var response = xmlreqs[i].xmlhttp.responseText;
                                //alert(name + '     ' + response);
                                if (name != "assignCase")
                                    document.getElementById(div_id).style.top = 15;
                                    document.getElementById(div_id).style.left = 50;
                                if (name == "streetName" || name == "equipName")
                                    document.getElementById(div_id).style.top = 400;
                                    document.getElementById(div_id).style.left = 50;
                                if (name == "equipment" ) {
                                    document.getElementById(div_id).style.top = 150;
                                    document.getElementById(div_id).style.left = 475;
                                }

                                document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = response;

                                xmlreqs.splice(i,1); i--;
                                urlAr.splice(i,1); i--;

                        } else {
                                xmlreqs.splice(i,1); i--;
                                urlAr.splice(i,1); i--;
                        }
                }
        }
   } else {
       //alert('at else');
        for (var i=0; i < xmlreqs.length; i++) {
      //alert(i + ':' + name + ':' + xmlreqs.length);
                if (xmlreqs[i].xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                        if (xmlreqs[i].xmlhttp.status == 200 || xmlreqs[i].xmlhttp.status == 304) {
                                // 200 OK
                                // get response info here before splicing - see below on creating an xml object
                               // alert('200 was here' + name);
                                var response = xmlreqs[i].xmlhttp.responseText;
                                var len = response.length;
                                if (name == "streetName" || name == "equipName" || name == "city" || name == "zip" || name == "grid") {
                                    document.getElementById(div_id).style.top = 270;
                                    document.getElementById(div_id).style.left = 50;
                                } else if (name == "upstream"){
                                      document.getElementById(div_id).style.left = 600;
                                      document.getElementById(div_id).style.top = 150;
                                } else if (name == "equipment" ) {
                                    document.getElementById(div_id).style.top = 125;
                                    document.getElementById(div_id).style.left = 500;
                                } else if (name == "pingMeter"){
                                    document.getElementById(div_id).style.left = 1025;
                                    document.getElementById(div_id).style.top = 210;
                                } else if (name == "assignCase") {
                                    //document.getElementById(div_id).style.top = 60;
                                    //document.getElementById(div_id).style.left = 120;
                                } else {
                                    document.getElementById(div_id).style.top = 400;
                                    document.getElementById(div_id).style.left = 50;
                                }

                                document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = response;

                                if (response == "") {
                        //            xmlreqGET(urlAr[i]);
                                    xmlreqs.splice(i,1); i--;
                                    urlAr.splice(i,1); i--;
                                } else {
                                    //document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = response;
                                    xmlreqs.splice(i,1); i--;
                                    urlAr.splice(i,1); i--;
                                }
                        }

                }
               if (xmlreqs[i].xmlhttp.readyState < 4) {
                  // confirm('at nloading');
                        document.getElementById(div_id).style.top = 270;
                        document.getElementById(div_id).style.left = 50;    
                        document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = "<div align=center class='fixedwidth' style='background-color:#ffff8f'>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp; &nbsp;<img src='omscontrol/common/images/loading.gif' width='20'><Font size=1> Loading Content....Please Wait!&nbsp; &nbsp;</Font><br>&nbsp;</div>";
                        } 
        }
   }
    alert(document.getElementById('firstOption'));
    document.getElementById('firstOption').focus();
   } catch (e) { }


    }
```

Example from the servlet as to how the HTML is being written. This isn't really something I want to get into changing at this time.

```
    comboOption = new StringBuffer();
                        /* Version 1.0.2 */
                        comboOption.append("<select id=\"" + id + "\" class='fixedwidth' style=\'background-color:#ffff8f\' size='4' "
                                + "onchange=\"popVal(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value); populateValues('" + id + "');\">");
                        comboOption.append("<option value=''>" + "No Matches Found!" + "</option>");
                        /* Version 1.0.2 */

                    comboOption.append("</select>");
                    out.print(comboOption.toString());
```

I had tried adding the focus() to a script, and putting it into that last append. I'm not sure if that is even something that could work, but it didn't for me.

EDIT 2:
I added document.getElementById('firstOption').focus();  to the very end of the two readyState == 4 if conditions. I can tell that the element does exist at that time, but my focus actually ends on nothing. (I found that out by adding

```
    $(document.activeElement).change(function(){
                        alert("NEWFOCUS: " + document.activeElement.id);
                    });
```

to my JSP. If that isn't reliable, please tell me.)

Comment: Can you post the code and markup that you have currently?

Comment: It's sort of a complicated application that I inherited. Which parts would be helpful? I don't think showing the jsp page would give much more information. Would you like to see the places where I've got my focus() attempts currently?

Comment: @user1132296 you focus() function should be inside the readyState==4 condition.

Answer (score 1):

you have to append the input element first to the DOM before you call the focus function

```
var div = document.getElementById("dynamic");
$.ajax({
   ...
   success:function (data) {
     // append the new created input to the DOM
     ....
     div.appendChild(newInput);
     newInput.focus();

   }
});
```

You are probably trying to access `ajaxbox` before it is present in the DOM that's why you are getting a `null`

Comment: This is a common mistake, I've seen people make it quite often when dealing with AJAX requests.

Comment: Also, here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate. Sorry for the jQuery it was quickest to mock up the AJAX request. http://jsfiddle.net/pJgyu/25435/